# Border color + font color in HTML?

Tags: html, css, colors

How should I give color to a table tr along with a separate border color.

Here is my class properties in style.css.

```css
table tr {
  background: #9a9a9a;
  border-color: #000000;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell1</td>
    <td>Cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to give black color to the border and font color as white with background color as dark grey.

How to do this?

Comment: Pls add a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply border on `td`

```
tr td { 
      background: #9a9a9a;
      border:1px solid #000000;
      font-size: 21px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

`border` will apply from all 4 sides. you can change border sides with 
`border-top`, `border-bottom`, `border-left`, `border-right`

Answer (score 0):

Border is not allowed for table rows, but only for whole tables or table cells. However, you can use the outline property to draw a border. It only doesn't count towards the box model and you cannot set individual sides in terms of color, style or width.

To select a specific row, use a pseudo-class on the `tr`.

```css
td {
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

tr:hover {
  background: #666;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #table th {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #107DBA;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    #table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #e7e7e7;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    #table td {
        padding: 9px 2px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Tahoma;
    }
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>firstname</th>
    <th>lastname</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>john</td>
  <td>doe</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>sara</td>
  <td>cein</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>hamid</td>
  <td>hagh</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>maryam</td>
  <td>temori</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```